# How to ensure Laravel Single Auth?

Tags: php, laravel

```
$user->last_session = session_id();
$user->save();
```

To check if the session is valid I used below

```
if(session_id() != Auth::user()->last_session){
   Auth::logout();
   return true;
}
```

I would like to set Laravel Single Authentication, for version 4. But this not working.

Comment: How is this not working? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are re-setting a new value for the `last_session` field before you check if the last value is equal to the current value. You should first check if the session ID is equal to the `last_session` field in the database like so:

```
if(session_id() != Auth::user()->last_session){
   Auth::logout();
   return true;
}else{
   $user->last_session = session_id();
   $user->save();
}
```